# In Google Sheets, is it possible to collate + auto sort multiple columns of data into a single column?

Tags: google-sheets

I used this site to learn how to sort a two-column list, `{string, number}`.

I can't find a way to combine multiple two-column lists into a single, two-column list.

For example, in Major League Baseball (MLB) there are 6 divisions. For each division, I have a column-pair that lists that division's standings.  The first column lists the teams in that division, and the second column lists their total wins.

Example data:

|  | A | B | C | D | E | F | G | H | I | J | K | L |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **1** | **AL East** | **Wins** | **AL Central** | **Wins** | **AL West** | **Wins** | **NL East** | **Wins** | **NL Central** | **Wins** | **NL West** | **Wins** |
| **2** | New York Yankees | 12 | Cleveland Guardians | 10 | Texas Rangers | 11 | Atlanta Braves | 12 | Chicago Cubs | 10 | Arizona Diamondbacks | 8 |
| **3** | Boston Red Sox | 11 | Chicago White Sox | 9 | Seattle Mariners | 9 | Miami Marlins | 9 | Cincinnati Reds | 9 | Colorado Rockies | 8 |
| **4** | Baltimore Orioles | 10 | Detroit Tigers | 9 | Los Angeles Angels | 8 | New York Mets | 8 | Milwaukee Brewers | 8 | Los Angeles Dodgers | 7 |
| **5** | Tamba Bay Rays | 9 | Kansas City Royals | 8 | Oakland Athletics | 8 | Philadelphia Phillies | 8 | Pittsburgh Pirates | 6 | San Francisco Giants | 7 |
| **6** | Toronto Blue Jays | 7 | Minnesota Twins | 7 | Houston Astros | 6 | Washington Nationals | 6 | St. Louis Cardinals | 4 | San Diego Padres | 6 |

The table above has a total of 12 columns.

I'd like to then add another two columns that sort the entire league by wins.  Here is an example of the first 7 rows:

|  | M | N | O |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **1** | **Team** | **Wins** |  |
| **2** | Atlanta Braves | 12 |  |
| **3** | New York Yankees | 12 |  |
| **4** | Boston Red Sox | 11 |  |
| **5** | Texas Rangers | 11 |  |
| **6** | Baltimore Orioles | 10 |  |
| **7** | Chicago Cubs | 10 |  |

The issue is that it seems every sort/lookup can only see a single column. Meaning even if you can have it look at the range A:L, it can't actually see columns B, D, F, G, J, L, all at once. I tried doing a Query Array but that didn't collate everything into a single column.

How can this be done?

The janky solution is to have another column that lists every team and uses VLOOKUP to populate wins then use SORT in another column to sort that single column of all the teams. But I'd like to cut out that middle step, if possible, just for the sake of limiting clutter/simplifying the process.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the full range as two columns with WRAPROWS, you can use also QUERY to delete empty rows:

```
=SORT(QUERY(WRAPROWS(A:L,2),"WHERE Col1 is not null"),2,0)
```

Comment: If the source data has a header row, you might want to leave out the `sort()` and use just `=query(wraprows(A1:L, 2), "where Col1 is not null order by Col2 desc", 1)`.

Comment: Yeah, thought it after leaving the computer! Thanks for pointing it out!

Answer (score 0):

If your data is in `Sheet1!A1:L6` like this:

| AL West | Wins | Al Central | Wins | AL East | Wins | NL West | Wins | NL Central | Wins | NL East | Wins |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Houston Astros | 12 | Chicago White Sox | 10 | New York Yankees | 12 | Arizona Diamondbacks | 10 | Chicago Cubs | 12 | Atlanta Braves | 10 |
| Los Angeles Angels | 2 | Cleveland Guardians | 6 | Boston Red Sox | 11 | Colorado Rockies | 6 | Cincinnati Reds | 6 | Miami Marlins | 6 |
| Oakland Athletics | 3 | Detroit Tigers | 8 | Baltimore Orioles | 10 | Los Angeles Dodgers | 8 | Milwaukee Brewers | 8 | New York Mets | 8 |
| Seattle Mariners | 4 | Kansas City Royals | 7 | Tamba Bay Rays | 9 | San Diego Padres | 7 | Pittsburgh Pirates | 7 | Philadelphia Phillies | 7 |
| Texas Rangers | 5 | Minnesota Twins | 9 | Toronto Blue Jays | 7 | San Francisco Giants | 9 | St. Louis Cardinals | 9 | Washington Nationals | 9 |

...you can get this:

| Division | Team | Wins |
| --- | --- | --- |
| AL West | Houston Astros | 12 |
| AL East | New York Yankees | 12 |
| NL Central | Chicago Cubs | 12 |
| AL East | Boston Red Sox | 11 |
| Al Central | Chicago White Sox | 10 |
| NL West | Arizona Diamondbacks | 10 |
| NL East | Atlanta Braves | 10 |
| AL East | Baltimore Orioles | 10 |
| AL East | Tamba Bay Rays | 9 |
| Al Central | Minnesota Twins | 9 |
| NL West | San Francisco Giants | 9 |
| NL Central | St. Louis Cardinals | 9 |
| NL East | Washington Nationals | 9 |
| Al Central | Detroit Tigers | 8 |
| NL West | Los Angeles Dodgers | 8 |
| NL Central | Milwaukee Brewers | 8 |
| NL East | New York Mets | 8 |
| Al Central | Kansas City Royals | 7 |
| NL West | San Diego Padres | 7 |
| NL Central | Pittsburgh Pirates | 7 |
| NL East | Philadelphia Phillies | 7 |
| AL East | Toronto Blue Jays | 7 |
| Al Central | Cleveland Guardians | 6 |
| NL West | Colorado Rockies | 6 |
| NL Central | Cincinnati Reds | 6 |
| NL East | Miami Marlins | 6 |
| AL West | Texas Rangers | 5 |
| AL West | Seattle Mariners | 4 |
| AL West | Oakland Athletics | 3 |
| AL West | Los Angeles Angels | 2 |

...like this:

```
=let( 
  unpivot_, lambda(d,f,g,let(r_,lambda(t,o,h,chooserows(t,sequence(h,1,o))),c_,lambda(t,o,w,choosecols(t,sequence(1,w,o))),s_,lambda(r,c,h,w,r_(c_(d,c,w),r,h)),l_,lambda(c,s_(1,c,1,1)),hr,hstack(s_(1,1,1,f), "Division", "Team", "Wins" ),i,sequence(1,(columns(d)-f)/g,f+1,g),n,tocol(iferror(ø),true),reduce(hr,sequence(rows(d)-1,1,2),lambda(z,r,let(e,s_(r,1,1,f),s,reduce(n,i,lambda(t,c,let(x,s_(r,c,1,g),if(single(x)="",t,vstack(t,hstack(e,l_(c),x)))))),vstack(z,s)))))), 

  unpivoted, choosecols(unpivot_(hstack(arrayformula(row(Sheet1!A1:L6)), Sheet1!A1:L6), 1, 2), 2, 3, 4), 
  
  query(unpivoted, "order by Col3 desc", 1) 
)
```